# Манифест приложения WinAPI (С++)

Tags: c++, winapi

Никогда не писал манифесты к приложениям. Надо сделать так, чтобы программа запрашивала админский доступ при запуске. Знаю, что где-то в файле манифеста надо прописать "requireAdministrator", только где понятия не имею, так как схемы данного xml не знаю и документации как-то мало.

IDE - NetBeans, компилятор - MinGW, сборка статическая.

Как этот манифест описать и подключить из ресурсов?

Comment: вроде как нужно скомпилировать `windres res.rc -o res.o`, в `res.rc` строка `1 24 ".manifest"`, в `.manifest` - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"><trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"><security><requestedPrivileges><requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel></requestedPrivileges></security></trustInfo></assembly>`

Comment: А в res.h ничего об этом не надо писать？ И в самом коде манифест никак не упоминается？ Просто скомпилить и он сам подтянется, так？

Comment: В .h ничего, это ресурс он и отдельно в файле может быть. Число 24 в .rc файле это тип RT_MANIFEST, как оно там это все работаает я сам не знаю

Comment: Спасибо! Напишите ответ, я "лайкну". Правда не понятно что за "1 24", я вместо этого писал APP_MANIFEST MANIFEST "имя_фалйла.exe.manifest" - не работало, а 1 24 нормально. Где про это прочитать не подскажете?